# Change data displayed in RadioButton.Item React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

In my code I am looping through an array of data and displaying that data as Radio button alternatives. What I want to do is to take away the item that the user has chosen from the other lists that are rendered. I have only succeeded to take away the data from the current list that the user has expanded, not from the other ones.

My code:

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import {RadioButton, List} from 'react-native-paper';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { theme } from '../../../../utilities/themes';
import * as firebaseAction from '../../../redux/actions/firebaseActions';


export default function ChoicesComponent({props, callback}) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    //const getDataFsRedux = useSelector(state => state.firebase.fsData);
    //const getDataFsRedux = useSelector(state => state.firebase.fsData);
    const getSceduelesFsRedux = useSelector(state => state.firebase.fsDataSchedueles);
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState('Klicka för att välja svar');
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);
    const [schedueleArray, setSchedueleArray] = useState(null);
    const [testing, setTesting] = useState(false);
    const [newArray, setNewArray] = useState(getSceduelesFsRedux);

    const docName = "turlistor"

    //let newArray = null;

    const handlePress = () => setExpanded(!expanded);

    useEffect(() => {

        callback({id: props.id, text: value});


        if(getSceduelesFsRedux !== null ) {
            setNewArray(getSceduelesFsRedux.turlistor)

            //setTesting(!testing)
            //console.log("NEW get cheduele data.length: ", getSceduelesFsRedux.turlistor.length)
            //console.log("NEW get data is not null")
            //newArray = getSceduelesFsRedux;
            //console.log("NEW array before change: ", newArray)
            // if (getSceduelesFsRedux.turlistor.includes(value)) {
            //     const nArray = getSceduelesFsRedux.turlistor.filter(item => item !== value)

            //     console.log('TAG New array, ', nArray)
            //     //console.log("NEW ARRAY: ", nArray)


            //     setNewArray(nArray)
                

            //     console.log("::::::: includes value :::: ")
            //     console.log("value: ", value)
            // }
        }


    }, [value, getSceduelesFsRedux, expanded]);

  return (

        <List.Section>
            <List.Accordion title={value} expanded={expanded} onPress={handlePress}>
                <RadioButton.Group onValueChange={newValue => {setValue(newValue)}}value={value}>

                    {/*getSceduelesFsRedux ? getSceduelesFsRedux.turlistor.map((item) => (
                        <RadioButton.Item color={theme.colors.primary}
                        key={item.id}
                        label={item}
                        value={item}
                        />
                    )) : 'Loading'*/}

                    {newArray ? newArray.map((item) => (
                        <RadioButton.Item color={theme.colors.primary}
                        key={item.id}
                        label={item}
                        value={item}
                        />
                    )) : 'LOADINNGNGNNGNG'}

                </RadioButton.Group>
            </List.Accordion>
        </List.Section>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  list: {
    
  },
});
```

This is how my list looks like: [Theese are the lists that can be expanded, there are 6 lists to expand and each list has there alternatives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kBGF.jpg)

[When a user chooses an alternative here I want to take it away from thee next list that the user expands.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8a2J6.jpg)

I have been stuck for days! I have been stuck in my own thinking bubble.

Comment: I think we may need to see a more complete code example. I don't see where you do any radio option filtering to eliminate any selected values. Think you could stand up an [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/) demo of your code that we could inspect and debug live?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you could get `getSceduelesFsRedux` from state in the component which calls ChoisesComponent. So instead of getting it here, get it in its parent component, store it in a state variable, pass the setstate and state to the ChoisesComponent's and inside the ChoisesComponent just copy the state minus what you selected and setState.

Comment: I see now that wouldn't work entirely. 

You could, next to what I said above, add another state variable with an array which contains the previous choices. 0 would be the first ChoisesComponent's selected value, 1 would be the second etc...

Then pass the setstate of that state variable to the ChoisesComponent and add its selection to the array. Now inside the parent of ChoisesComponent you will have an array containing all the selected alternatives, all you will have to do is filter the selected alternatives array out of the main alternatives array.